# Cancel Banner Notification in iOS8 Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, voip, xcode6.3

My title might not accurately depict my question, so I apologize. I have looked for a solution to creating this level of functionality but I am unable to find it.

I am creating a VoIP application for iOS 8. When a user receives a call I am displaying a notification with a 12 second ringtone. While this notification is in progress if the call disconnects I want the Incoming Call notification to disappear and display a Missed Call notification immediately. This level of functionality is possible because Viber does it.

Currently, I am sending a silent push notification when a Incoming Call is available. This is my payload...

```
aps = {
        "content-available" = 1;
      };
      category = INCOMING;
      from = "+15555554220";
```

Upon receiving the silent push I am creating a Local Notification like this ...

```
if ([userInfo[@"category"] isEqualToString:@"INCOMING"]) {
                NSLog(@"application: didReceiveRemoteNotification:  fetchCompletionHandler: Incoming Call Notification Received");

                NSLog(@"application: didReceiveRemoteNotification:  fetchCompletionHandler: Sending Local Notification For Incoming Call");

                // Get Caller Contact Info
                NSDictionary *contact = [self findContactInfoForNumber:userInfo[@"from"]];

                NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Incoming Call: %@",userInfo[@"from"]];

                if (contact != nil) {
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Incoming Call: %@ %@",contact[@"firstName"],contact[@"lastName"]];
                }

                UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Incoming Call" forKey:@"type"];
                notification.userInfo = infoDict;
                notification.category = @"INCOMING_CALL_CATEGORY";
                notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
                notification.alertBody = message;
                notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                notification.soundName = @"ring.m4a";

                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

            }
```

Then, once the call is disconnected I am sending another silent push notification for a missed call...

```
aps = {
        "content-available" = 1;
      };
      category = MISSED;
```

Once received I am canceling all local notifications like this...

```
if ([userInfo[@"category"] isEqualToString:@"MISSED"]) {
     NSLog(@"application: didReceiveRemoteNotification:  fetchCompletionHandler: Missed Call Notification Received");
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

The issue I am encountering is that on the lock screen it behaves exactly the way I want it to. I receive the incoming call notification and when the caller hangs up that notification immediately disappears from notification center and a missed call notification is there in the place of it. However when the phone is on the home screen. A banner is shown and then it plays the whole ringtone then displays the missed call. Does anyone know the reason why this is happening? Does anyone have any solutions to achieve this level of functionality? Like I said before the app Vider is a prime example of what I want my app to do.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: were you able to find an answer to this ?