# Replace push/local notification like WhatsApp

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, whatsapp

I want to achieve feature like WhatsApp where user gets push notification when someone calls them and notification says *" Call from X"* and if you don't receive call or click on notification for 30 sec. Another push notification is received which says *"Missed call from whatsapp.."*. But the last notification is removed from the stack or replaced or no longer visible. How can we achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use UILocalNotification for this. In messenger app I worked on we used following workflow for exact same feature:

- When User1(U1) calls User2(U2), server sends an empty push notification to U1. This way nothing will show in notification center.
- U1 starts socket connection (available even if app is in background but unavailable if killed)
- U1 register for socket events, collects info about the caller and shows off [UILocalNotification](http://uilocalnotification%20show%20alert) with 30 seconds timer
- After 30 seconds U1 emits message over socket to inform server that it missed a call, U2 receives that event and displays appropriate message
- U1 [removes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158264/cancel-uilocalnotification) UILocalNotification from notification centre

Comment: How do you remove the notification from notification centre? is their any API for it ? The link you referenced cancels the scheduled notification not the notification already in notification centre.

Comment: Use API for canceling, it will work. Docs says following: "Calling this method also programmatically dismisses the notification if it is currently displaying an alert.".

Comment: @Taseen, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355704/cancel-banner-notification-in-ios8-not-working), it describes how to implement it... Also have a look at [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html), which is intended to be used for VoIP push notifications...